# Extract string from malformed URL using Javascript, based on multiple characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring

I have a bunch of Wordpress blogs that pull html from reference pages using a PHP DOM '**scraper** .' It generates the path to the logo based on the url of the site and a fixed file path all the logos are known to be in. Problem is, we just implemented a CDN.

The logo paths, on the blogs, went from `<img src="http://www.example.com/images/logo.png" />`
to `<img src="http://www.example.com//cdninfoinalongstring/morecdnstuff/images/logo.png" />`, the latter being obviously incorrect.

I need the src to be changed to:

```
<img src="//cdninfoinalongstring/morecdnstuff/images/logo.png" />
```

I am familiar with `.indexOf()` and things like `.substring()`, `.split()`, and `.pop()`, but attempts to reference multiple characters, in this case remove the string before "//," failed.

Comment: So you just want to remove the `http://www.domain.com` from all strings? Do you know the domain or is it always different?

Comment: Wouldn't be better to change that server-side? Not everybody has JS enabled.

Comment: @Oriol - If they have javascript disabled, not seeing the logo would be the least of their problems. On this site and most all others. But, to be fair, that's a debate with a scope far beyond this question. In this case, the change cannot be made on the server-side of things.

Comment: @Leeish - The domain will be different on each site, each with it's own unique CDN path to its logo. It will be formatted in the same way on each site, though. The domain, then the //, then the CDN path. I just need to remove everything before the two slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do this

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll('img[^=http://www.domain.com]');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].src = arr[i].src.replace(/^http(s)?:\/\/[^\/]+/, "");
}
```

Comment: If you know the domain, something as simple as this will work.

Comment: In a sense, I will not know the domain. I will, but it's different in every case and could change.

Comment: @user1729506 glad to have helped you :)

Comment: @AmitJoki - Apologies for backtracking, after having accepting your answer, but I've encountered an error: `Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'img[^=http://www.domain.com]' is not a valid selector.`

Comment: Just figured out the issue. Had to put 'src' before the CSS selector ^.

Answer (score 0):

Since the domain will not always be known, I tried this and seemed to meet with some success:

```
theLogoPath = $('div.logo a img').attr('src');
theLogoCdnPath = theLogoPath.split("//")[2];
$('div.logo a img').attr('src','//' + theLogoCdnPath);
```